# React Native FREE REAL maps

Tags: react-native

I'm currently developing a React Native app where I need to display simple city maps with a few markers. My main goal is to find a completely free solution for this task. I came across "react-native-maps" which seems to be an open-source and free option. However, I've stumbled upon something called "map tiles," and from my understanding, some map tile services might require payment or offer free plans with limitations.

I'm not entirely clear on what map tiles are and why some of them are paid services or have free plans with limitations. Is there truly no fully free alternative available for implementing maps with markers in a React Native app? I'm looking for any guidance or recommendations for open-source and free tools that can help me achieve this without running into hidden costs down the line, especially considering map tiles.

Any advice on navigating the options for map tiles, or suggestions for completely free mapping solutions that integrate well with React Native, would be greatly appreciated. I'm open to exploring different approaches, including serving my own map tiles if that's a viable and cost-effective strategy.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!